# USB Microphone gives error 'Device or Resource Busy'

Tags: hardware, microphone, arecord

I've recently purchased [this microphone](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B076Z974S4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for use with my Pi 3, but I can't seem to get it to work. I run `arecord -l` and the Pi can see my device:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [(LCS) USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But when I try to record a test with `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -d 3 test.wav` I get the following error:

```
arecord: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Is there anything I can do to get around this?